# HTTP Headers Information server setting

Tags: php, http-headers

I am using following code to show the XML file

```
header('Content-type: application/xml')
```

But xml file is generated when I see in View Page Source but it is not showing in xml format
on page.

Is there any Apache Environment or HTTP Headers Information setting I need to do ?

please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Try capitalizing the `t` in `Content-Type`

Comment: As far as I know "Content-type" is actually correct according to the specifications - the 't' in type shouldn't be uppercase... not that it seems to matter normally in real terms.

Comment: @CD001 The standard says it should be "Content-Type:" http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17 but you're right, it shouldn't matter unless the browser is extremely strict which all browsers should be, but unfortunately none are.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. I stand corrected - I'll remember that in future ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `text/xml` instead. Unless you're coding for a specific application such as RSS. (RSS would be `application/rss+xml`)

Comment: have you tried `Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8` ? Just in case there's a character throwing it out.